# Trying to create file without succes - file appears elsewhere?

Tags: java, writer

I tried to create 3 empty files in my home directory, using this:

```
     this.mainpath = System.getenv("HOME"+"/");
     this.single = new File(mainpath + "sin.r");
     this.complete = new File (mainpath + "com.r");
     this.ward = new File (mainpath+"w.r");
```

I was unter the impression that this would give me the files desired. However, if I search my home directory, or any other directory, for this files, none of them exists. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I just find out: I do get a file, but not in my home directory, but the path to it would be /home/myname/NetBeansProjects/myorojectname/nullsin.r.

However, I specifically wanted to create the file in my home!

Well, my code now reads:

```
this.mainpath = System.getenv("user.home");
        this.mainpath = this.mainpath + "/";
         this.single = new File(mainpath + "sin.r");
         this.single.createNewFile();
         System.out.println(this.single.getAbsolutePath());
         this.complete = new File (mainpath + "comp.r");
         this.complete.createNewFile();
         this.ward = new File (mainpath+"w.r");
         this.ward.createNewFile();
```

The "success" of this, however, is that I get an IOException at  the first createNeWFile(): File not found.

as for my code how I tried to write sth into those file, there it is:

```
     FileWriter writer1 = null;
    FileWriter writer2 = null;
    FileWriter writer3 = null;

    try {
         writer1 = new FileWriter(single);
         writer2 = new FileWriter(complete);
         writer3 = new FileWriter(ward);

         writer1.write("x = cbind(1,2,3)");
         writer2.write("x = cbind(1,2,3)");
         writer3.write("x = cbind(1,2,3)");
         writer1.flush();
         writer2.flush();
         writer3.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());

    } finally {
        try {
            writer1.close();
            writer2.close();
            writer3.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());

        }
```

Comment: You were mistaken. Creating a `new File` doesn't create a physical file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `getProperty()` instead

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Also, the `/` should be appended after getting the directory path.

```
this.mainpath = System.getProperty("user.home");
this.single = new File(mainpath + "/sin.r");
this.complete = new File (mainpath + "/com.r");
this.ward = new File (mainpath+"/w.r");
```

Comment: @newnewbie, your edit shows you're still using `getenv()`. Switch to `getProperty()` it's OS neutral. `getenv()` would return `null` in your case because there isn't any environment variable named `user.home`.

Comment: I am working on linux...but you are right forgot about getProperty, apparently put in the new code without deleting the old. wait a second

Comment: It's better to use `new File(String, String)` instead of manually creating the "file path": `single = new File(mainpath, "sin.r");` that will work correctly on all plaforms.

Comment: thanks all of you, basically my own stupidity. However: How is that supposed on all plattforms as one uses / and the other \? I was going to introduce 2 different cases for windows and linux anyway

Comment: @newnewbie, use the constructor suggested by a_horse_with_no_name as it would take care of the path separator for you. The first parameter represents a string path or `File` reference for a directory.

Comment: I see what...wait.... are you telling me that way I would end up in the home in both windows and linux, because the constructor would change mainpath (already a string with several separators) so that it is fine? that would save me 2-3 hours of ork!

Comment: @newnewbie Yes, `getProperty("user.home")` would give you home directories (with correct path separators) in all OSs. Use of `File(String, String)` would extend the same benefit to file names.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the "createNewFile"-method for each of the objects you've declared to actually create them.

Comment: I did that, see above,  to no avail